# How to get access to parent app's bundle identifier inside watch app's plist?

Tags: ios, xcode

My iOS app (lets call it myApp) come with a watchOS app (lets call it myWatchApp). myApp have multiple targets (one for PRD environment and one for UAT) and each one have separate bundle identifier (for example co.company.myApp-UAT and co.compony.myApp-PRD).

every time i want to send a test flight for each target, i must change the value of `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` inside myWatchApp's info.plist to specific bundle identifier(co.company.myApp-UAT or co.company.myApp-PRD).

is there any way to not do that each time?